# Corollary of Kolmogorov zero-one law

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

Here is another corollary of the theorem: Kolmogorov zero-one law given in my textbook (Probability path). How can I apply the said theorem given that if $X_n$ are independent random variables, $[\sum_nX_n \mbox{ converges}]$ has probability 0 or 1. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that this event is in the tail $\sigma$-field.

Comment: Is it taking the lim sup of Xn?